# Graph algorithm

Tags: algorithms, animations

I must make an animation of one algorithm on graph, I must make something like bfs, starting in one vertex and increasing values of other vertices. Then we take another vertex and start once again, and in the end values of all vertices will be equal. I tried sth to solve this problem, but I haven't any idea, how to make it. There is sth what I've written:

```
    \documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}

\tikzstyle{vertex}=[circle,fill=black!25,minimum size=15pt,inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{selected vertex} = [vertex, fill=red!24]
\tikzstyle{blue vertex} = [vertex, fill=blue!24]
\tikzstyle{edge} = [draw,thick,-]
\tikzstyle{weight} = [font=\big]
\tikzstyle{selected edge} = [draw,line width=5pt,-,red!50]
\tikzstyle{ignored edge} = [draw,line width=5pt,-,black!20]

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}%

\begin{document}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}
\def \n {10}
\def \a {1}
\def \b {2}
\def \c {3}
\def \d {4}
\def \e {5}
\def \f {6}
\def \g {7}
\def \h {8}
\def \i {9}
\def \j {10}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[->,scale=1.8, auto,swap]

            \foreach \pos/\name/\z in {{(0,0)/a/\a}, {(1,-1)/b/\b}, {(1.5,-2)/c/\c},
                                    {(1.3,-2.5)/d/\d}, {(0.6,-2.5)/e/\e}, {(2,-2.66)/f/\f}, 
                                    {(1.3,-3.5)/g/\g},{(0.6,-3.5)/h/\h},{(2,-3.33)/i/\i},
                                    {(1.9,-1.3)/j/\j}}
                \node[vertex] (\name) at \pos {\z};


            \foreach \source/ \dest /\pos in {a/b/bend right, b/c/bend left, c/d/, d/e/bend right,
                                             d/f/bend left, e/h/bend right, f/i/bend right, h/g/bend right,                                                  i/g/bend left, c/j/bend right, c/j/bend left}
                \path (\source) edge [\pos] node {} (\dest);
           %there must be an animation

        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

One option using a key-value approach (through the [`keyval`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/keyval) package) to change the values for the nodes. You simply use the overlay specifications and the command `\mylistvalues` to update the desired values for each slide; for example,

```
\mylistvalues{va=1,vb=2,vc=3,vd=4,ve=5,vf=6,vg=7,vh=8,vi=9,vj=10}
```

assigns the initial values for all the nodes and

```
  \mylistvalues<5->{va=10,vb=9,vc=8,vd=7}
```

changes the values for the four first vertices, from the fifth slide onwards.

Here's an animation produced with this approach:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}
\usepackage{keyval}

\makeatletter
\define@key{myani}{va}{\def\Va{#1}}
\define@key{myani}{vb}{\def\Vb{#1}}
\define@key{myani}{vc}{\def\Vc{#1}}
\define@key{myani}{vd}{\def\Vd{#1}}
\define@key{myani}{ve}{\def\Ve{#1}}
\define@key{myani}{vf}{\def\Vf{#1}}
\define@key{myani}{vg}{\def\Vg{#1}}
\define@key{myani}{vh}{\def\Vh{#1}}
\define@key{myani}{vi}{\def\Vi{#1}}
\define@key{myani}{vj}{\def\Vj{#1}}
\newcommand<>\mylistvalues[1]{\only#2{\setkeys{myani}{#1}}}
\makeatother

\tikzstyle{vertex}=[circle,fill=black!25,minimum size=15pt,inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{selected vertex} = [vertex, fill=red!24]
\tikzstyle{blue vertex} = [vertex, fill=blue!24]
\tikzstyle{edge} = [draw,thick,-]
\tikzstyle{weight} = [font=\big]
\tikzstyle{selected edge} = [draw,line width=5pt,-,red!50]
\tikzstyle{ignored edge} = [draw,line width=5pt,-,black!20]

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}%

\def\n{10}
% Initialize the values
\mylistvalues{va=1,vb=2,vc=3,vd=4,ve=5,vf=6,vg=7,vh=8,vi=9,vj=10}

\begin{document}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[->,scale=1.8, auto,swap]
            \foreach \pos/\name/\z in {{(0,0)/a/\Va}, {(1,-1)/b/\Vb}, {(1.5,-2)/c/\Vc},
                                    {(1.3,-2.5)/d/\Vd}, {(0.6,-2.5)/e/\Ve}, {(2,-2.66)/f/\Vf}, 
                                    {(1.3,-3.5)/g/\Vg},{(0.6,-3.5)/h/\Vh},{(2,-3.33)/i/\Vi},
                                    {(1.9,-1.3)/j/\Vj}}
{
  \mylistvalues<2->{va=2,vb=3,vc=4,vd=5,ve=6,vf=7,vg=8,vh=9,vi=10}
  \mylistvalues<3->{va=3,vb=4,vc=5,vd=6,ve=7,vf=9,vg=9,vh=10}
  \mylistvalues<4->{va=4,vb=5,vc=6,vd=7,ve=8,vf=9,vg=10}
  \mylistvalues<5->{va=5,vb=6,vc=7,vd=8,ve=9,vf=10}
  \mylistvalues<6->{va=6,vb=7,vc=8,vd=9,ve=10}
  \mylistvalues<7->{va=7,vb=8,vc=9,vd=10}
  \mylistvalues<8->{va=8,vb=9,vc=10}
  \mylistvalues<9->{va=9,vb=10}
  \mylistvalues<10>{va=10}

  \node<1->[vertex] (\name) at \pos {\z};
}
            \foreach \source/ \dest /\pos in {a/b/bend right, b/c/bend left, c/d/, d/e/bend right,
                                             d/f/bend left, e/h/bend right, f/i/bend right, h/g/bend right,                                                  i/g/bend left, c/j/bend right, c/j/bend left}
                \path (\source) edge [\pos] node {} (\dest);

        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

By the way, instead of the old `\tikzstyle` syntax you should switch to the more convenient `\tikzset` syntax.